# If else a twig in a row, bug not working standart code

Tags: twig, twig-extension

I need a little help, I'm trying to switch to a twig темплате of standard php code. But something is wrong, although i read the template documentation well.

My Code

```
<?php echo $pr['price'] . ($pr['unit'] ? '/' . $pr['unit'] : ''); ?>

{{ pr.price . pr.unit ? '/' . pr.unit : '' }}
```

How do you think I can solve the problem with this one-line check, something wrong with the rules and the check?

Answer (score 0):

In `twig` you use `~` to concat strings, u'd also need to add parantheses, just like you did in `php`

```html
{{ pr.price ~ (pr.unit ? '/' ~ pr.unit : '') }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/k0uou6)